# Gradle 2.0 - Proper way to load a java properties file?

Tags: java, gradle

In Gradle, you could load data from a properties file via:

```
apply from: "version.properties"
```

As of Gradle 2.0, this generates a warning:

```
"Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtensi‌​on.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties."
```

What is the canonical means of the same behavior in the latest and greatest version of Gradle?

I'm able to work around this by defining a helper method of course, but I'm curious if there's a more concise way.

Comment: The link is broken, but [the documentation referred to is here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html).

Comment: Thanks for fixing that. I had checked that earlier as well, but seems there's no mention of this particular use case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to load data from properties files other than `gradle.properties` has always been to use Java's `Properties` class:

```
def versionProperties = new Properties()
file("version.properties").withReader { versionProperties.load(it) }

// Perhaps a future Groovy version could simplify this to:   
def versionProperties = file("version.properties").loadProperties()
```

Loading properties via `apply from: "version.properties"` only ever worked by coincidence, and only if all property values were numbers (because then property file syntax becomes a subset of Groovy syntax). The deprecation warning will already occur in 1.x (at least for the last year's worth of 1.x versions). 2.0 has finally removed the ability to introduce properties on-the-fly without declaring them with `def` or `ext.`, which explains why it fails hard.